# Problem with Vagrant Installation on windows

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtual-machine, homestead, vagrant-windows

I'm going to use homestead to develop a laravel application on Windows.
So I installed VirtualBox and then, Vagrant and it went well as expected.
But when I type vagrant on command line and hit Enter, to make sure that it works, I see this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.18/gems/vagrant-2.2.18/bin/vagrant:111:in `<main>'
        1: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require': cannot load such file -- vagrant (LoadError)
        32: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.18/gems/vagrant-2.2.18/bin/vagrant:111:in `<main>'
        31: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:147:in `require'
        30: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:158:in `rescue in require'
        29: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:158:in `require'
        28: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.18/gems/vagrant-2.2.18/lib/vagrant.rb:338:in `<top (required)>'
        27: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.18/gems/vagrant-2.2.18/lib/vagrant.rb:338:in `each'
        26: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.18/gems/vagrant-2.2.18/lib/vagrant.rb:346:in `block in <top (required)>'
        25: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.18/gems/vagrant-2.2.18/lib/vagrant.rb:346:in `each'
        24: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.18/gems/vagrant-2.2.18/lib/vagrant.rb:329:in `block in <top (required)>'
        23: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.18/gems/vagrant-2.2.18/lib/vagrant.rb:329:in `load'
        22: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.18/gems/vagrant-2.2.18/plugins/commands/cloud/plugin.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        21: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
        20: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
        19: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.18/gems/vagrant_cloud-3.0.5/lib/vagrant_cloud.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        18: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
        17: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
        16: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.18/gems/excon-0.85.0/lib/excon.rb:38:in `<top (required)>'
        15: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
        14: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
        13: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.18/gems/excon-0.85.0/lib/excon/socket.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        12: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
        11: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
        10: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/resolv.rb:38:in `<top (required)>'
         9: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/resolv.rb:168:in `<class:Resolv>'
         8: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/resolv.rb:171:in `<class:Hosts>'
         7: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
         6: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
         5: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/win32/resolv.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
         4: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
         3: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
         2: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/win32/registry.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
         1: from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/win32/registry.rb:72:in `<module:Win32>'
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/mingw64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/win32/registry.rb:72:in `find': unknown encoding name - CP720 (ArgumentError)
```

I have installed VirtualBox 6.1.26  and Vagrant 2.2.18 64-bit. Virtualization is enabled on my Windows. I also have disabled hyper-v.
Is there anyone who knows what is wrong?

Comment: #reza @reza Please specify apps version for example virtual box version e.t.c

Comment: Decreased app version to virtual box 5.1.26 from 6.1.26 vagrant 2.0.0 from 2.2.18

Comment: @peter I want to use the latest version of laravel and it requires VirtualBox 6.1.x

Comment: @peter I just installed vagrant 2.0.0 and it worked! thanks peter

Comment: please mark my solution as answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235658/discussion-between-peter-and-reza).

Comment: @peter Now, when I try to boot vagrant in the homestead folder, it says vagrantFile requires version 2.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution#1**

Decreased app version
to virtual box 5.1.26 from 6.1.26
And
vagrant 2.0.0 from 2.2.18

**Solution#2**

Re-install app

Comment: this does not work on windows 10 and just throws message that this app cant start because it causes security and performance issues on windows, when you try to run virtual box manager